# How to write the messages in the Email with two line spacess for each Message

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

```
  message.Body = "Message: " + ex.Message +Environment.NewLine + "Data:"+ ex.Data 
                 + Environment.NewLine + "Stack Trace:" + ex.StackTrace;
```

I am using Environment.NewLine., its going to next line perfectly but I need to put two line separated with ---------------- in between each message Data StackTrace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of Environment.NewLine, put:

```
"\n\r----------------\n\r"
```

You can store this in a const and then reuse:

```
const string Sep = "\n\r----------------\n\r";
message.Body = "Message: " + ex.Message + Sep + "Data:" + ex.Data 
                 + Sep + "Stack Trace:" + ex.StackTrace;
```

NB: \n\r produces a new line and a carriage return.

To reuse the code in a confirmation page, for example, replace the "\n\r" with

```
"<br />"
```

Answer (score -2):

u can try "<br/> ------------------"

u can write html tags in message body but not in the title

Comment: that is because you aren't displaying in a web page.  To get the newline in an email, see my answer to this question.